# Ephesoft key value extraction

Tags: ephesoft

When I do a key value extraction on an uploaded batch, it doesn't work and proceeds to the end of the process none the less.

How can I ensure that if my key value extraction doesn't work, that user will be asked to enter the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you added the `VALIDATE_DOCUMENT` plugin? That should force the manual review of the key value extraction.

Another thing to check could be the presence of kv extraction rules for each field.

Finally, I would check the workflow, since the `KV_PAGE_PROCESS` and `KEY_VALUE_EXTRACTION` may should be loaded and swithed to ON.

Comment: If I could ask (maybe I should open a different question) would you have any idea why once I upload a batch, I wouldn't be able to start it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to upload batches, you can check my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594530/impossible-to-upload-batch-in-ephesoft-community I use the import folders to put the batches in share folders  and they start automatically in the meantime